# Insert more than 1 million data in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    movie_id = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __int__(self):
        return self.userid
```

I can't enter 1 million data one by one using django admin panel, so
how would i populate database of both model with 1 million data ?

Comment: With `.buk_create`.

Comment: you can use management commands and populate database using code

Comment: Like everyone else has ever done: use your RDBMS dedicated features (as surprinsing as it might be, loading huge datasets in a database as fast as possible is a very common use case, and has been for decades, so most RDBMS have at least one - and usually many - options for this).  Or write a script to insert your data in the database (much less efficient, but sometimes you need to process your source data before you can inject them, or you may want to use the ORM's validation, etc).

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be to directly import it into the database bypassing the ORM and Django as a whole or writing a script that will insert it into the database from a csv file and running that using your manage.py console.